# Python: create a Class which attributes are objects from another classes possible?

Tags: python, class, object, nested

Is it possible to create a class with some of its attributes = object of other classes?

class SENSORS:

```
def __init__(self):
    # The attributes of the class that will be available for external use
    self.temperature = None
    self.humidity = None
    self.distance = None
    self.light = None
    self.sound = None
    self.url = None
    self.base_url = "http://..."

    # Instantiating sensor objects
    self.SOUND = NEW OBJECT FROM CLASS SOUND
    self.LIGHT = NEW OBJECT FROM CLASS LIGHT
    self.DISTANCE = NEW OBJECT FROM CLASS DISTANCE
    self.TEMP = NEW OBJECT FROM CLASS TEMPERATURE
```

Comment: why shouldn't it work? `None` and strings are also other objects.

Comment: Ok thank you so my problem isn't in the class initialization but in another part of class delcaration.

Answer (score 1):

Have you *tried* it?

```
>>> class A(object):
...   pass
...
>>> class B(object):
...   a = A()
...
>>> b = B()
>>> b.a
<__main__.A object at 0x021490B0>
```